# "I feel stressed" or "I feel stressful"? Which one is correct?

Tags: word-choice

I say "I feel stressful" but my  teacher, a native speaker of English, says that I should say "I feel stressed".

Both *stressful* and *stressed* are adjective.

Which is correct, I feel stressed or I feel stressful?

Why do  we have  "It is very interesting" but not "It is very stressing" yet "It is very stressful"?

Comment: *stressful* means that something causes stress. If that's how you feel, then say it, but you probably mean *stressed*.

Comment: What makes you think you know more about the English language than your English teacher? That said, I'm sure you are stressful — to your teacher, who in turn feels stressed by you.

Comment: what is wrong with this question? why it got voted down? nonsense

Comment: @JakeRegier That wasn’t very nice.

Comment: The popularity of  "feel stressed" is a fairly recent phenomenon, soaring since about 1980. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feel+stress%2Cfeel+stressed%2Cfeel+stressful&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeel%20stress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeel%20stressed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeel%20stressful%3B%2Cc0

Comment: As I recall, we didn't talk about "stress" in a psychological sense until sometime in the '70s, when psychologists popularized the term. I don't remember how we described the feeling before then.

Comment: Well, it goes back farther than I thought....   http://www.healthcentral.com/anxiety/c/1950/30437/history-term-stress/  but it wasn't in common use in the '40s, '50s and '60s. At least not in books (see my ngram link, above)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think you can find relevant definitions of 'stressed' and 'stressful' in any recent (and reasonably good) dictionary. Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary certainly provides such definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Stressful* means "causing stress". You can check any dictionary.

Environment, circumstances, work can be stressful, that is they are causing stress for somebody.

So if you say "I feel stressful," it would mean "I feel that I am causing stress (for somebody)." The word *stressful* is just not used in this way.

Correct expression is "I feel stressed."

Answer (score 0):

stressed - *adjective* - feeling very worried or anxious.

stressful - *adjective* - full of or causing stress.

Therefore, stressed has to do with how you feel, and stressful has to do with what you are full of.

`I am stressful` would likely be more correct than `I feel stressful`, much like one would say `The tank is full of gas.`

Comment: Why do  we have  "It is very interesting" but no "It is very stressing" but "It is very stressful"?

Comment: @user105551 That is a good point. Some things are the way they are, because they always have been. I can tell you the what, but not the why.

Comment: @user105551 Stressing can be used as a verb in a sentence related to speech. `He is stressing the 'but'`.

Comment: but "stress" in that sentence has different meaning

Comment: @user105551 Think about it in the context. `He is stressing.` Does that mean he causes you stress or is stressing a word in speech? How would we know? We wouldn't know. However, it would be the speech context, since stressing is not an adjective.

Comment: But there would be no doubt if you said he was _distressing_.  And I have never heard _distressful_.

Answer (score -1):

The underlying reason your teacher is right (not necessarily correct) is that the teacher is teaching you idiomatic American English. Native speakers use and are familiar with the "I feel stressed" phrasing; "I feel stressful", while technically correct according to your dictionary definitions, is not idiomatic, and native American English speakers are likely to be puzzled by or derisive of the usage.